# How to print out a toString for this class?

Tags: java, class

I have written a polynomial class and a tester class. The polynomial class can evaluate and return the sum of the polynomial when the degree, coefficients and the value of x are provided. Basically I need to edit my toString method so it actually prints out the polynomial

```
          import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Polynomial {

private int degree;
private int [] coefficient;
private double evaluation; 
private double sum;
private double value;
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);



public Polynomial(int degree)
{
    this.degree = degree;
    coefficient = new int [degree+1];

}


public void setCoefficient(int coefficient) 
{
    this.coefficient[this.degree] = coefficient;
}


public int getCoefficient(int degree)
{
    return coefficient[degree];
}



public double Evaluate(double value)
{
    this.value =value;
    for (int i=0; i<=degree; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter coefficent for position " + i);
        this.coefficient[i] = key.nextInt();
        evaluation = Math.pow(value, i)*this.coefficient[0] ;
        this.sum += evaluation;

    }
        return sum;

}   






/** Standard toString method */
//needed something better than this below...needed an actual polynomial printed out 
public String toString()
{
     return "The degree of the polynomial is " + degree + " and the value for which it has been evaluated is" + value;

}
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to print out something like this "7.0 + (2.0)x^1 + (5.0)x^2 + (1.0)x^4" but don't know how? Or you want to print out something different?

Comment: hmmm yeahh ...I want the system to be able to print out the coefficients that the user enters with ex beside them and the according square above it this is how the output is supposed to look lke:Enter polynomial degree: 4
Coeff for degree 0: 7
Coeff for degree 1: 2
Coeff for degree 2: 5
Coeff for degree 3: 0
Coeff for degree 4: 1
Polynomial: 7.0 + (2.0)x^1 + (5.0)x^2 + (1.0)x^4
Enter a value of x for which to evaluate the polynomial: 3
For x = 3, polynomial = 139.0
Enter a value of x for which to evaluate the polynomial: -3.1
For x = -3.1, polynomial = 141.2021

Comment: I know how to do everything else except I can't figure out how to print out the polynomial . That's the only problem

Comment: i think your implementation has problems such as your evaluating values for a polynomial , each time you want to evaluate , you must enter the polynomial

Comment: You are not saving the coefficient for each degree separately.  Each time your user enters a coefficient for a position, you overwrite the coefficient for the previous position.  You need to store the coefficients in an array going from 0 to the degree, and then you will be able to print them out in the toString function.

Comment: you can save the coefficients in a vector, say coefs, then do something like System.out.print(coefs[0]); for (int i=1; i<=degree; i++) {System.out.print(" " + coefs[i] + 'x^' + i);}

Comment: thx David and everyone here. I will implement the suggestion and see how it goes.I have never used an array to store user entered data. Ill be back when I figure it out. Have a nice weekend

Comment: @theredfox24 I've added an answer which shows you how you might proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be along the lines you should be proceeding.  I included the `main` function in your `Polynomial` class for simplicity, so you will have to modify that if you want to keep it in your tester class.  Notice that degree has been made into an integer array of size `degree +1`(allocated in the constructor):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Polynomial {

private int degree;
private int [] coefficient;
private double evaluation; 
private double sum;
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
public Polynomial(int degree)
{
    this.degree = degree;
    coefficient = new int [degree+1];

}

public void setCoefficient(int coefficient, int degree) 
{
    this.coefficient[degree] = coefficient;
}

public int getCoefficient(int degree)
{
    return coefficient[degree];
}

public void Evaluate(double value)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=degree; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter coefficent for position " + i);
        this.coefficient[i] = key.nextInt();
        evaluation = Math.pow(value, i)*this.coefficient[0] ;
        this.sum += evaluation;

    }
}   
public double getSum(){
    return sum;
}

public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    for (int i=0; i <= degree; i++)
    {
        s += coefficient[i];
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                s += " + ";
                break;
            case 1:
                s += "x + ";
                break;
            default:
                s += "x^" + i + ((i==degree)?"":" + ");
        }
    }
    return s; 

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int degree;
    double sum;
    int coefficient;

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the degree of the polynomial");
    degree=key.nextInt();

    Polynomial fun = new Polynomial(degree);



    fun.Evaluate(3.0);

    System.out.println(" The sum of the polynomial is " + fun.getSum());

    System.out.println(fun);

}

}
```

Comment: thank you David you're amazing! I had actually used an arraylist but I think your method is much better

Comment: You are very kind!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of making the objects of a class printable is to supply a `toString` method in the class, which specifies how to express objects of that class as a `String`.  Methods such as `println` and other ways of outputting a value will call a class's `toString` method if they need to print an object of that class.

You should adopt the same pattern with your `Polynomial` class - write a `toString` method with all the output logic.  Then in your `PolynomialTester` class, all you need to write is `System.out.println(fun);` and the rest will just happen.  You'll find this far more versatile than writing a method that actually does the printing.  For example, you'll be able to write something like

```
System.out.println("My polynomial is " + fun + " and " + fun + " is my polynomial.");
```

if that's your idea of fun.

---

A few other things concern me about your class.

- You seem to be only storing one coefficient and one exponent.  I'd expect a polynomial to have a whole array of coefficients.
- You have fields for `evaluation` and `sum` - but these only really make sense while a polynomial is being evaluated.  They're not long-term properties of the polynomial.  So don't store them in fields.  Have them as local variables of the `evaluate` method, and return the result of the evaluation.
- I'd expect a class like this to be immutable.  That is, you should provide all the coefficients when the object is created, and just never change them thereafter.  If you do it that way, there's no need to write setter methods.

---

So I've written my own version of your class, that fixes those issues listed above, and implements a `toString` method that you can use for printing it.  A second version of `toString` lets you specify which letter you want to use for `x`.  I've used "varargs" in the constructor, so you can construct your polynomial with a line such as

```
Polynomial fun = new Polynomial (7, 2, 5, 0, 1);
```

specifying the coefficients from the constant term through in order to the coefficient of the term with the highest exponent.  Or you can just pass an array.

See that I've changed the logic a wee bit - my version prints the polynomial in the conventional order, from highest to lowest exponent.  It leaves off the decimals if the coefficient is an integer.  It doesn't print a 1 in front of an `x`.  And it deals cleanly with `-` signs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Polynomial {

    private double[] coefficients;

    public Polynomial(double... coefficients) {
        this.coefficients = Arrays.copyOf(coefficients, coefficients.length);
    }

    public int getDegree() {
        int biggestExponent = coefficients.length - 1;
        while(biggestExponent > 0 && coefficients[biggestExponent] == 0.0) {
            biggestExponent--;
        }
        return biggestExponent;
    }

    public double getCoefficient(int exponent) {
        if (exponent < 0 || exponent > getDegree()) {
            return 0.0;
        } else {
            return coefficients[exponent];
        }
    }

    public double evaluateAt(double x) {
        double toReturn = 0.0;
        for (int term = 0; term < coefficients.length; term++) {
            toReturn += coefficients[term] * Math.pow(x, term);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString('x');
    }

    public String toString(char variable) {

        boolean anythingAppendedYet = false;
        StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder();

        for (int exponent = coefficients.length - 1; exponent >= 0; exponent--) {
            if (coefficients[exponent] != 0.0) {
                appendSign(toReturn, exponent, anythingAppendedYet);
                appendNumberPart(toReturn, exponent);
                appendLetterAndExponent(toReturn, exponent, variable);
                anythingAppendedYet = true;
            }
        }

        if (anythingAppendedYet) {
            return toReturn.toString();
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    private void appendSign(StringBuilder toAppendTo, int exponent, boolean anythingAppendedYet) {
        if (coefficients[exponent] < 0) {
            toAppendTo.append(" - ");
        } else if (anythingAppendedYet) {
            toAppendTo.append(" + ");
        }
    }

    private void appendNumberPart(StringBuilder toAppendTo, int exponent) {
        double numberPart = Math.abs(coefficients[exponent]);
        if (numberPart != 1.0 || exponent == 0) {
            //Don't print 1 in front of the letter, but do print 1 if it's the constant term.
            if (numberPart == Math.rint(numberPart)) {
                // Coefficient is an integer, so don't show decimals
                toAppendTo.append((long) numberPart);
            } else {
                toAppendTo.append(numberPart);
            }
        }
    }

    private void appendLetterAndExponent(StringBuilder toAppendTo, int exponent, char variable) {
        if (exponent > 0) {
            toAppendTo.append(variable);
        }

        if (exponent > 1) {
            toAppendTo.append("^");
            toAppendTo.append(exponent);
        }
    }
}
```

So I tested it with this class

```
public class PolynomialTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial fun = new Polynomial (7, 2, 5, 0, 1);
        System.out.println(fun.getDegree());
        System.out.println(fun.evaluateAt(3));
        System.out.println(fun);
    }
}
```

and the output was

```
4
139.0
x^4 + 5x^2 + 2x + 7
```

then I realised that you wanted to be able to input the coefficients in a loop.  So I changed `PolynomialTester` to this.  See how I build the array and *then* create the object.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PolynomialTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the degree:");
        int degree = input.nextInt();

        double[] coefficients = new double[degree + 1];
        for( int exponent = 0; exponent <= degree; exponent++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the coefficient of x^" + exponent);
            coefficients[exponent] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        Polynomial fun = new Polynomial (coefficients);
        System.out.println(fun.evaluateAt(3));
        System.out.println(fun);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Note that if you *really* want your polynomial to be printed in "reverse" order, with the constant term first, you could change the loop in the `toString` method to this.

```
for (int exponent = 0; exponent < coefficients.length; exponent++) {
```

Comment: awesome class Mr.Wallace I'll have to study for a few years more to get to your level :).Have a great week

Comment: It's very kind of you to say so, but honestly, I don't think I've used any particularly advanced techniques.  There are lots of little pieces of logic to this class - like dropping the decimals if the coefficient is a whole number, dropping the coefficient if it's 1, showing the minus signs in the right place, and so on.  But I think it's all logic that you can understand, and that you'd be able to reproduce for yourself.  The trick with something like this is to build it a little at a time - get each little piece working before you add the next piece.

Comment: Anyway, I hope you manage to learn something from my effort here, and good luck with your ongoing study.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a class member String poly, then modify the following method.

```
public void Evaluate(double value)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=degree; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter coefficent for position " + i);
        this.coefficient= key.nextInt();
        evaluation = Math.pow(value, i)*coefficient ;
        this.sum += evaluation;
        this.poly = "";
        if(coefficient != 0)
        {
            if(i > 0)
            {
                this.poly += " + " + Integer.toString(coefficient) + "x^" + Integer.toString(i); // you may replace x with the actual value if you want
            }
            else
            {
                this.poly = Integer.toString(coefficient)
            }
        }
     }
}
```